# Remove non-numeric items in a listu using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with an array in Javascript that contains several IDs in them but I would like to filter out all non-numeric entries using regex and return that array of just numbers. For example, I have `myArray = ['131125150138677','CI%20UW%20SYSTEMS%20S','040964100010832']` where I want to get rid of the second item in the list since it's non-numeric.

Comment: well that array is invalid so I assume the real one has quotes?

Comment: @epascarello yes, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use Filter and test to see if they are numbers

```js
var myArray = ['131125150138677', 'CI%20UW%20SYSTEMS%20S', '040964100010832']
var filtered = myArray.filter(Number)
console.log(filtered)

var filtered2 = myArray.filter(s => s.match(/^\d+$/))
console.log(filtered2)
```